# ruby mixins errors

Tags: ruby, mixins

I'm confused with the following piece of code.

HTTParty library has class method named `def self.get(..)`.

I include it in the `Client` module and then include that `Client` module in my `Line` class and access the `get` method in my `def self.hi()` method.
But when I run, it throws out the error:

```
ruby geek-module.rb
geek-module.rb:12:in `hi': undefined method `get' for Line:Class (NoMethodError)
  from geek-module.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

Why I'm not being able to access that `get` method of HTTParty?
Following is the code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

module Client
  include HTTParty
end

class Line
  include Client

  def self.hi
    get("http://gogle.com")
  end
end

puts Line.hi
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access self.get method because you use `include HTTParty`, include makes methods acessible by instances of class not class himself, your `hi` method is class method but `get` method is the instance method. If you use something like:

```
class Line
 include Client

 def hi
   get("http://gogle.com")
 end 
end

line = Line.new
line.get
```

I think it should work

... or just use `extend Client` rather than `include`

Comment: Highlight code by putting it in backticks ```, not by bolding it.

Comment: Its not the case. If you see the source of HTTParty its just the syntactic sugar to use `include` instead of `extend`. i.e. `get` is class method. Its extended by the ruby hook method `def included(base)` and inside the block just extend `base.extend`.

Answer (score 0):

So, when you `include HTTParty` in the `Client` module you can access the `get` method through `Client.get`. And when you include `Client` in the `Line` class you can access the `get` method through `Client.get` too. Actually, if you want to use the `get` method in your Line class, you don't need to include it. So:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

module Client
  include HTTParty
end

class Line

  def self.hi
    Client.get("http://google.com")
  end
end

puts Line.hi
```

or if you want the `get` method in your `Line` class you can use something like that:

```
class Client
  include HTTParty
end

class Line < Client
  def self.hi
    get("http://google.com")
  end
end

puts Line.hi
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how to accomplish this without Inheriting, using the mixins only?

Comment: I think you can't. Why do you can't use `Client.get`?

Comment: I can use `Client.get`, but I wanted to know the reason why just using `get` doesn't work?